# How to indicate return itself class in python?

Tags: python, oop

I mean when we have something like

```py
def returnNumber() -> int | None:
   return 1
```

Is there any way to specify in the init function that we are going to return the class itself?

```py
class Tree:
  def __init__(self) -> Tree: #hereeee
```

because in language server auto completion appears

```py
() -> None #this with a class init
() -> int|None # this with the function example
```

Comment: `__init__()` doesn't return a class or an object, it always returns `None` and cannot be changed.

Comment: when you instantiate an instance, python first calls `__new__()` which returns the instance, then calls the object's `__init__()` to initialize it, and `__init__()` itself has to return `None` as it is not responsible for creating the object.